# Breakable frame with one column text and picture in the corner

Tags: tcolorbox

I would like to produce framed layoutwith a picture in the upper left corner and text on the right, in a column. I currently use tcolorbox (for breakable frames) with tabu inside. Using tabu feels like too heavy for this task, plus it makes the frame unbreakable. How would you solve this in an elegant way? Using things like `\llap`, `\hangindent` and so on is acceptable.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `breakable` tcolorbox with a large left margin and use `overlay` to add the figure when you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, breakable, left=3cm, notitle, 
         overlay first={\node[anchor=north west, outer sep=2mm] 
               at (frame.north west) {\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{example-image}};}]
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great and elegant! So much to learn every day. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
  \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

  \pagestyle{empty}                 
  \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}           
  \usepackage{flowfram}                                 % column layout
  \usepackage{tikz}

  % frame setup (flowfram package)
  % left frame
  \newflowframe{0.2\textwidth}{\textheight}{0pt}{0pt}[left]
      \newlength{\LeftMainSep}
      \setlength{\LeftMainSep}{0.2\textwidth}
      \addtolength{\LeftMainSep}{1\columnsep}

  % small static frame for the vertical line
  \newstaticframe{1.5pt}{\textheight}{\LeftMainSep}{0pt}

  % right frame
  \addtolength{\LeftMainSep}{1.5pt}
  \addtolength{\LeftMainSep}{1\columnsep}
  \newflowframe{0.7\textwidth}{\textheight}{\LeftMainSep}{0pt}[main01]


  \begin{document}

  % Left frame
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \begin{figure}
      \hfill
      \includegraphics[width=0.6\columnwidth]{duck1.jpg}
      \vspace{-7cm}
  \end{figure}

  \vspace*{1mm}
  \framebreak


  % Right frame
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  3 May. Bistritz.-Left Munich at 8:35 P.M., on 1st May, arriving at   Vienna   early next morning; should have arrive at 6:46, but train was an hour late. Buda-Pesth seems a wonderful place, from the glimpse which I got of it from the train and the little I could walk through the streets. I feared to go very far from the station, as we had arrived late and would start as near the correct time as possible. I found my smattering of German very useful here, indeed, I don't know how I should be able to get on without it.
I was not able to light on any map or work giving the exact locality of the Castle Dracula, as there are no maps of this country as yet to compare with our own Ordance Survey Maps; but I found that Bistritz, the post town named by Count Dracula, is fairly well-known place. I shall enter here some of my notes, as they may refresh my memory when I talk over my travels with Mina.
It was on the dark side of twilight when we got to Bistritz, which is very interesting old place.

  \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I accepted the other answer but this one is also valuable. Thanks.