# How to use the awesomebox with custom image from external file and add double vertical line

Tags: symbols, packages, boxes

I'm looking for a way to modify or make an alternative to the warning/alarm messages in text alike this one from `awesombox` package:
[image]

What I need to do is:

1. replace the warning sing on the left with an externally loaded image
2. use a double vertical line as a separator

To get something like this:
[image]

In the [documentation](http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/graphics/awesomebox/awesomebox.pdf) I found that the image can be replaced with symbols from a certain font, but no mentioning of using externally loaded image and no explanation of how to make a doubled line.

How it should be implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `awesomebox` is implemented as a tabular (i.e., a table) with the icon in one column, the text in another, and the colored vertical bar in between. You can do the same without the package with a `tabularx` environment. The double lines can be shown using `||` as column separator.

The column with the text can use `X` as column separator, which means 'a paragraph column with the remaining available width'.

To get the image top-aligned with the text the `align=t` option for `\includegraphics` provided by the package `graphbox` can be used. Additionally, to improve vertical spacing around the warning box I added 12pt on the top and bottom.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcommand{\customwarning}[1]{%
\vskip12pt
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{2.5cm}||X}
\centering\includegraphics[align=t,width=2cm]{warningsign} & #1 \\
\end{tabularx}
\vskip12pt
}
\begin{document}
\customwarning{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam aliquet libero quis lectus elementum fermentum. Fusce aliquet augue sapien, non efficitur mi ornare sed. Morbi at dictum felis. Pellentesque tortor lacus, semper et neque vitae, egestas commodo nisl.}

Other text

\customwarning{This is a frog}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Edit: with an optional argument to specify the image (either just the filename or the image with a path specification).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}

% the default filename is 'warningsign', change this if you have a different default name
\newcommand{\customwarning}[2][warningsign]{%
\vskip12pt
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{2.5cm}||X}
\centering\includegraphics[align=t,width=2cm]{#1} & #2 \\
\end{tabularx}
\vskip12pt
}
\begin{document}
% image given as argument
\customwarning[warningsign]{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam aliquet libero quis lectus elementum fermentum. Fusce aliquet augue sapien, non efficitur mi ornare sed. Morbi at dictum felis. Pellentesque tortor lacus, semper et neque vitae, egestas commodo nisl.}

Other text

% without argument, default value is used for the image name/location
\customwarning{This is a frog}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work. Could you, please, expand the answer so the location of the image can be forwarded as an argument?

Comment: @Yehor see edit.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of `tcolorbox`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\newtcolorbox{myColorBox}{%
  sidebyside,
  sidebyside align=top,
  lower separated=true,
  lefthand width=2.5cm,
  arc=0pt,
  left=0pt,right=0pt,top=0pt,bottom=0pt,
  colback=white, 
  enhanced, 
  segmentation style={draw=black,double distance=3pt,solid},
  boxrule=0pt,
  sidebyside gap=20pt,
  width=\textwidth,
}

\newenvironment{MyBox}[1][example-image] % replace "example-image"  with file name of default image
               {\begin{myColorBox} \includegraphics[width=2.5cm,valign=t]{#1}\tcblower}
               {\end{myColorBox}}

\begin{document}


\begin{MyBox} % omit optional argument for defautlt image
\lipsum[5]
\end{MyBox}


\begin{MyBox}[example-image-a] % use optional argument to insert non-default image
\lipsum[5]
\end{MyBox}

\lipsum[5]
\end{document}
```

Comment: A `sidebyside` box is not `breakable`. If you need it I'd suggest [this alternative](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/366655/1952)